# Is there a way to create or track metrics using aws cloudwatch for processes that are running in a server?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there a way to create or track metrics using aws cloudwatch for processes that are running in a server

For example my instance has these processes running

Python,
kafka (zoo keeper)

is there anyway to find whether python, kafka  is working or not in aws ec2 instance, using cloud watch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a script having the `ps` command which will check the process. Run this script through `crontab`. Using crontab, you can continuously keep an eye on the process.

You can use below commands to configure the script in `crontab`

```
crontab -l # This is to list the crontab
crontab -e # This is to edit the crontab
```

Then you can use `put-metric-data` to send the data to cloud watch.

Below is the sample script :

```
========Sample script======
#!/bin/bash

Process_Check=$(<your-custom-ps-command>)

aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name memory-usage --dimensions Instance=<Instance-ID>  --namespace "Custom" --value $Process_Check
```

The above script will collect the process details and then send it to AWS cloud watch using `put-metric-data`. Keep on sending data to CloudWatch through `crontab` for better visibility.

Refer below links to create and view the custom cloudwatch metric.

[Create Custom CloudWatch Metrics](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-custom-metrics/)

[Publishing Custom Metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html)

Comment: cron is working but could'nt able to see the metrics in the cloudwatch